# ReactJS useEffect opposite of deps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Normally the `effect` of `React.useEffect` is only activated **if** values in the `deps` list change.

What I want is the reverse of that. I want for it to be activated **unless** values in the list change.

BTW, I know that wrappers around chart.js already exist.

But, people asked for a concrete example, so here it is.

For example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, memo, useMemo } from "react";
import merge from "lodash/merge";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  ChartType,
  ChartData,
  ChartOptions,
  ChartConfiguration,
} from "chart.js";

type ChartInstance = InstanceType<typeof ChartJS> | null;

export type ChartProps = Readonly<ChartData> &
  Readonly<ChartOptions> & {
    readonly type?: ChartType;
    readonly height?: number | string;
  };

export const Chart = memo<ChartProps>(
  ({
    type = "line",
    height = "20em",
    responsive = true,
    maintainAspectRatio = false,
    animation = { duration: 0 },
    hover = { animationDuration: 0 },
    responsiveAnimationDuration = 0,
    labels = [],
    datasets = [],
    legend: { display = false, ...legend } = {},
    ...rest
  }) => {
    const [canvas, ref] = useState<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
    let chart: ChartInstance = null;

    const options: ChartConfiguration = {
      type,
      data: { labels, datasets },
      options: {
        responsive,
        maintainAspectRatio,
        animation,
        hover,
        responsiveAnimationDuration,
        legend: { display, ...legend },
        ...rest,
      },
    };

    const destroy = () => {
      if (chart) {
        chart.destroy();
        chart = null;
      }
    };

    chart = useMemo<ChartInstance>(() => {
      destroy();
      return canvas ? new ChartJS(canvas, options) : null;
    }, [canvas, type]);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (chart) {
        merge(chart, options).update();
      }
    });

    useEffect(() => destroy, []);

    return (
      <div style={{ position: "relative", height }}>
        <canvas ref={ref} />
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

It makes no sense to update the chart if we just created it.

If `useMemo` executes, then the `useEffect` following it should not.
Otherwise, it needs to be executed every time.

The component is wrapped in `React.memo`, so if render occurs,
that means that some of the chart props changed and the chart needs to be either recreated or updated.

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` maybe? I don't think that you should be using the `useEffect` hook for your solution

Comment: @ZombieChowder in `useLayoutEffect` the `deps` argument works exactly the same way

Comment: Is the variable a prop or state value?

Comment: Can you give the concrete use case?

Comment: @AdamAzad it's a prop of type string

Comment: That's an interesting question but what's the use for this? Components should display the current state of the app. If the state doesn't change, the components shouldn't too so your requirement is quite strange. In React, components may theoretically re-render for no obvious reasons. Do you want to count wasted re-renders or something?

Comment: @marzelin there is another `useEffect` (or rather `useMemo`) that runs when that variable changes. I don't want the second one to run if the first one runs. Sort of an else case.

Comment: You might need to a HOC that modifies your component props in such way that triggers the call for that function (you will need to move it out of `useEffect`

Comment: Question is also, do you want to run it **on** every render, or **after** every render, unless... some ways to solve this, but the use case isn't all that clear.

Comment: @Trace yes, as it says in my original question, I do want to run it on (or, I guess, after) every render, unless that variable changes. Ideally, in a perfect world, `useEffect` would simply allow you to pass two functions, and then one of the two would be called based on whether or not `deps` changed.

Comment: @EugeneKuzmenko In that case, can't you put a condition in the body of the functional component? I don't see a reason to use `useEffect`, as you use it to execute code **after** every render, and indeed the callback is called when the argument value is changed. You can get access to the previous value with `useRef`.

Comment: @Trace because then I would have to store the previous value somehow and make the comparison manually. I would have to basically replicate the functionality of `useEffect`.

Comment: @EugeneKuzmenko it looks like you have arrived at a solution that you need to x if y is this that. In this case, x and y are not supposed to work like that. Sure there can be hacks around it but question is this really a solution. Its better if you can give your problem statement, so that others can maybe provide a better solution without any hacks.

Comment: @amit77309 there you go. I updated the question with my actual component

Comment: In your code it looks like you want to update the chart when the options change, yesno?

Comment: @Trace options always change, if they don't change the render will not happen at all. The component is wrapped in `React.memo`. I want to either destroy and recreate it if `canvas` or `type` change (and not do the update), or if they don't change, then I want to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to revert `useEffect` dependency-checking behavior. It can be done, but it would be an unnecessary hack, especially that you don't use a clean-up function.

In your case, the most straightforward way is to introduce a variable (`shouldUpdateChart`) that will control whether the `useEffect` code should run. If the code inside of `useMemo` is run, its value is `false`, otherwise it's `true`:

```js
let shouldUpdateChart = true;

chart = useMemo < ChartInstance > (() => {
  shouldUpdateChart = false;
  destroy();
  return canvas ? new ChartJS(canvas, options) : null;
}, [canvas, type]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (shouldUpdateChart) {
    merge(chart, options).update();
  }
});
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest/best option is also the least obvious, lol. Thank you!

Comment: I get why existing libraries don't use a function component for this now :) I thought I could make it more elegant like this. But clean up becomes a nightmare as you inevitably run into circular dependencies. Needless to say, this is not the best approach.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to maintain some external reference to the previous value of a variable, run the effect on each render, and just bail out if that variable *does* change. Here's an example of how that might work. You could abstract this logic into its own custom hook.

```
let prevA;

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);
  const [b, setB] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (a !== prevA) {
      prevA = a;
      return;
    }
    console.log("a did not change");
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setA(a + 1);
        }}
      >
        Increment A
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setB(b + 1);
        }}
      >
        Increment B
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this is something I'm trying to avoid. My actual component has two `deps` variables. Which means that I will have to use `useState` 4 times just for this.

Comment: The useState was just for my example. You don’t need useState to hold references to existing dependencies, just create variable outside the scope of your component.

Comment: it's my bad really, I should've posted a complete example from the start. I tried to explain it with words...